# Access ObservableCollection items from property set

Tags: c#, wpf

Given the following class used as a WPF DataContext:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

and this Task class:

```
public class Task
{
    private string startTime;

    public Task ID { get; set; }
    public string StartTime
    {
        get { return startTime; }
        set
        {
            // Access ObservableCollection items
            startTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StartTime");
        }
    }
}
```

how can I, at the place in the code where you see "// Access ObservableCollection items", access the other items in the Tasks ObservableCollection so I can compare the StartTime of the instance being set to the StartTime of the other Task items in the Tasks ObservableCollection?

Comment: I'm not at all sure I would - it sounds like you might be trying to put ViewModel level functionality in your Model. Is there a good reason not to incorporate that comparison in the ViewModel?

Comment: @goobering: Can you give me some direction on how I could do that, given that I want to do the comparison when the property is being set?

Comment: Why do you need the comparison? What's your scenario?

Comment: @Liero: Because the StartTimes are bound to TextBoxes in a DataGrid, the user is able to change the StartTime. The StartTimes need to be chronological, so if the user changes the StartTime in one row, that time must be after the StartTime in the previous row and before the StartTime in the next row.

Comment: @Liero: More info: If the entered time is not acceptable, then I don't want to set the property. That's why my initial attempt was to try to do this in the property's set logic. I was able to do this by specifying the LostFocus attribute in the TextBox's XAML, and the value of that attribute was a method in the window's code-behind. If the TextBox's value wasn't acceptable, I could revert it to its original value. Because the LostFocus event happens before the property is set, the property therefore wouldn't be assigned a bad value. My new approach was an attempt to eliminate code-behind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can inject ViewModel into Task

   ```
   public class Task
   {
       private ViewModel viewModel;
       public class Task(ViewModel viewModel)
       {
           this.viewModel = viewModel;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

   However, this makes Task class usable only with ViewModel class, because they are loosely coupled.
2. you can perfom the StartTime validation in ViewModel. To do so you need to catch PropertyChanged events of all tasks.

   I created `ExtendedObservableCollection` that fires an event when property of any item changes:

   ```
   public class ExtendedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler ItemPropertyChanged;
       protected override void ClearItems()
       {
           foreach (var item in Items) item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
           base.ClearItems();
       }

       protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
       {
           item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
           base.InsertItem(index, item);
       }

       protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
       {
           this[index].PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
           base.RemoveItem(index);
       }

       protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
       {
           this[index].PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
           item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
           base.SetItem(index, item);
       }

       protected virtual void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          var handler = ItemPropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null) handler(sender, e);
      }
   }
   ```

   and finaly the validation or what whatever you need

   ```
   public class ViewModel
   {
      public ExtendedObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
      public ViewModel()
      {
          Tasks=new ExtendedObservableCollection<Task>();
          Tasks.ItemPropertyChanged += TaskPropertyChanged;
      }

      private void TaskPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          var changedTask = (Task)sender;
          if (e.PropertyName == "StartTime")
          {
             if (!IsStartTimeGreatedThenPrevious(changedTask )) 
                 changedTask.SetError("StartTime", "Start time has to be greated than in previous task)
          }
      }        
   }
   ```

you can add or remove items from Task collection and the `ExtendedObservableCollection` takes care of attaching/detaching to PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Mix view model with model, I wouldn't like my view model stuff inside my entities or DTOs

Comment: I assume, you are talking about first approach. Well, it depends on what the Task class is. Nobody said its a model entity or DTO. I mentioned the disadvantage of loosely coupling the two classes. The second approach does not mix Task and ViewModel.

Comment: So is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the Task class itself (which is how I actually have it, even though I omitted it from my original question) not recommended because the class is not part of the ViewModel?

Comment: It seems that using this approach, the validation would occur after the property has been set. I want the validation to occur before the property is set so that I can abort the setting of the property if validation fails.

Comment: 1. RE: _INotifyPropertyChanged on the Task_: no, that was not the point. Injecting viewmodel into model is not a good practice.

Comment: 2. RE: _abort setting the property_: from UX perspective I would not recommend you to to do it. If user enters incorrect value, it's better to show errormessage than to overwrite the value with small or no visual feedback for the user. Anyway, you can implement INotifyPropertyChanging or your own "cancelable" event that is called before the property is set. Here is example of such custom event: stackoverflow.com/a/7996089/475727

Comment: @Liero: After digesting your suggestions, I am going to try your Option 1 because the Task class indeed exists solely for the veiwmodel. I did a quick test by using the ObservableCollection object as the Task class argument (instead of the whole viewmodel object), and I was able to access the collection items, so I'm hopeful this approach will work. I now need to flesh out the actual validation logic to test this proof of concept.